# Are you able to define a named function within sorted()?

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to define a function in the 'key' parameter of a sorted() function.

I can get this to work by using a lambda function, however i was wondering if it was possible to split up my code, for readability (so i can spread it across multiple lines), to add a defined function in the key parameter.

```py
sorted_contacts = sorted(contacts_array, key= def d(x):
        #...do something here 
);
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Sorted_contacts = sorted(contacts_array, key= def d(x):
                                                    ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Python. Named functions are *statements*, and function arguments must be *expressions*.

The closest you'll get is a lambda function, but it can only have one line of code.

To solve your problem, you can define the function outside the call, and then reference it:

```
def d(x):
    ...
    return ...

sorted_contacts = sorted(contacts_array, key=d)
```

This is due to the fact that in Python, functions are **first-class objects**, which means that they are useable in an expression like any other object (integer, string, class instance, etc.)